# I am getting 500 as reply code when I try to delete a file from remote server using java FTPClient

Tags: java, file, ftp, java-io, ftp-client

When I try to delete a file using ftpclient I am getting reply code as 500. Can someone help me with the issue. As you can see in the commented section of the code I tried to move the file to other folder and I got the reply code as 500 as well.

```
public boolean sendFile(HttpResponse httpresponse, String accessionNumber)
            throws Exception {
    FTPClient ftpClient = null;
    boolean fileUploadStatus = false;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient(true);
        String fileName = "SampletesterFileNine.pdf";
        String remotePath = "/";
        String tempFile = remotePath + fileName;
        try {
            ftpClient.connect(server, this.port);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printstackTrace();
        }
        int reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
        logger.info("Reply code connect :" + reply);
        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            boolean login = ftpClient.login(userName, password);
            if (login) {
                if (ftps) {
                    ((FTPSClient) ftpClient).execPROT("P");
                }
                logger.info("Logged in to ftp server with host " + server);
            } else {
                logger.info("login failed");
            }
        } else {
            logger.info("login failed with exception");
        }
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        logger.info("Checking whether file exists or not!!");
        inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(tempFile);
        if(inputStream != null) {
            logger.info("File already exists");
            isFileExist = true;
            String toPath = "/failed/SampletesterFileNine.pdf";
            /*boolean renamed = ftpClient.rename(tempFile, toPath);
            logger.info("replycode is : " + ftpClient.getReplyCode());
            if(renamed) {
                logger.info("file moved to failed folder successfully");
            } else {
                logger.info("failed while moving file to failed folder");
            }  */
            boolean renamed = ftpClient.deleteFile(tempFile);
            logger.info("replycode is : " + ftpClient.getReplyCode());
            if(renamed) {
                logger.info("file moved to failed folder successfully");
            } else {
                logger.info("failed while moving file to failed folder");
            } 
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }   
        }           
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        try {
            if(inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close(); 
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printstackTrace();
        } 
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printstackTrace();
        }
    }
    return fileUploadStatus;
}
```

Comment: If it returns 500 you should be able to see a stack trace somewhere. Take a look at that and post it here. Otherwise we'll just be on a treasure hunt.

Comment: Do you get the same problem, if you remove the `retrieveFileStream` call?

Comment: Yes @MartinPrikryl , even after removing retrieveFileStream call I am facing  the same problem.

Comment: Then, it looks like 80% of your code is not relevant to your question. So please edit your question to show [mcve].